# view latest storing value in mysql order by group id' s

Tags: php, mysql

your query execute only  this is not correct see another example below

```
pid  customer id  invoice id     name  due amount make payment

 1      1001           086    sasi      36       sasi      10 
 5     1003            084    ram       100      ram       50
 7     1002            083    koushil   80       am         50
```

query is

SELECT *
FROM print_reciept pr
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT invoice_id, MIN(pid) AS min_pid
        FROM print_reciept
        WHERE due_amount != 0
        GROUP BY invoice_id
    ) t ON pr.invoice_id = t.invoice_id AND pr.pid = t.min_pid
WHERE due_amount != 0;

see this again  example

```
pid  customer id  invoice id  name  due amount make_pay paid_amount

1      1001           086    sasi      36       sasi      10   
2      1001           086    sasi      26       ram        5
3      1001           086    sasi      21       ravi      10 
4      1001           086    sasi      11       sasi      10     
5     1003            084    ram       100      ram       50
6     1003            084    raghu     50       sasi      10 
7     1002            083    koushil   80       am         50
8      1002           083     koushil  30        am        20
```

this is my result but i am already pay due 6 amount in same id  use invoice id 086

i need result

```
pid  customer id  invoice id     name  due amount make payment

 4      1001           086       sasi         11       sasi      10
 6     1003            084      raghu         50       sasi      10 
 8      1002           083     koushil        30        am       20
```

Comment: There are some columns in `SELECT` statement which is not defined in sample. where are these column and its data ?

Comment: all columns are view but does not change columns invoice_id,cust_id ,cust_name, changed columns pid is a auto increment ,invoice_date,  paid_amount, paymentmade ,makeapayment,due_amount,                                 after pay some amount create another row i need view new row only

Comment: you should add the data of another columns example same as 2nd line of your question. so we can help you.

Comment: Do you simply want to get the latest value of 'pid'? meaning you want to output the value (2) because you paid an amount and want to store that value to the database?

Comment: [edit]ggdgfdgfgdfgdfdfgdgf[edit]

Comment: see above example sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly.

If you want to get the last value of `invoice_id = 086`:

```
SELECT pid, cust_id, cust_name, date, invoice_id, invoice_date, 
  invoice_amount, paid_amount, paymentmade, makeapayment, due_amount, status
FROM print_reciept
WHERE invoice_id = 086
  AND due_amount != 0
ORDER BY pid DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to get the last value for each `invoice_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM print_reciept pr
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT invoice_id, MIN(pid) AS min_pid
        FROM print_reciept
        WHERE due_amount != 0
        GROUP BY invoice_id
    ) t ON pr.invoice_id = t.invoice_id AND pr.pid = t.min_pid
WHERE due_amount != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM print_reciept pr
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT invoice_id, MAX(pid) AS min_pid
        FROM print_reciept
        WHERE due_amount != 0
        GROUP BY invoice_id
    ) t ON pr.invoice_id = t.invoice_id AND pr.pid = t.min_pid
WHERE due_amount != 0;
```